# Two seemingly identical sed commands, one works, the other doesn't. Can you tell me why?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

There's something I'm having trouble understanding concerning sed behavior.

```
sed -n "/pattern/,$p" < input.inp > output.out
```

gives the following error

```
sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 10: `,' inattendue
```

(my system is in french).

```
sed -n '/pattern/,$p' < input.inp > output.out
```

Works fine

I've personnally used commands like

```
sed -n "/begin/,/end/p" < input.inp > output.out
```

with both single or double quotes, and they work just fine.

In case it's useful, I have sed version: sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: Yes! This is clearly a duplicate of bash $ sign behavior. Thanks Etan for catching that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In double quotes, the shell, not sed, will evaluate `$p`. Since you probably haven't set a variable named `p`, sed will only see `/pattern/,`. To prevent this from happening, you'd need to escape the `$` to the shell, by writing `\$` instead:

```
sed -n "/pattern/,\$p" < input.inp > output.out
```

(You can imagine that using single quotes is a lot easier on the eyes and brain, unless you need shell variables in your expression.)

Comment: @TomFenech: Heh, I was just editing to that effect. :)